# Django RESTful API Backbone.js/Mustache or stick with templates?

Tags: django, html, backbone.js, tastypie

I am working on a legacy Django site which is facing a rewrite to replace the existing Flex frontend with HTML5.  Further down the line there will be a mobile app (iPad only at this point), which will require a RESTful API.

My question is how much extra work would it be (turnaround is short < 2 months) to implement the web front end in something like backbone.js/mustache talking to a RESTful API on the Django side (probably tastypie) - in comparison to writing it as a standard Django app and bolting on the API later?  I'd prefer to go with the former, but just wondering if anyone has gone down this road and what issues you encountered.

Comment: This is a very subjective question and the answer will depend on your knowledge of backbone/javascript, and the complexity of the app.

Comment: if you have good JS team with some client side MVC experience Backbone is crazy fun and with bit of crunching probably you could easily pull it off - I know we've made it and it was fun!

Answer (score 0):

IME, RESTful APIs keep the server side clean, thus easier to maintain and scale. Your data models suddenly make sense as you need only worry about CRUD actions - the client makes the necessary API calls, thus allowing your endpoints to return only one type of data/dataset. 
Your routes can then become modular and its easier to keep things DRY.

However, reliance on client side JavaScript ultimately means more cross-browser consistency issues. Hope you made the right choice!